# how to calculate tow numbers in textbox instantly and the result chaged when i delete numbers?

Tags: c#

how to calculate tow numbers in textbox instantly  and the result chaged when i delete numbers from any textbox??
this is my code

```
        private void expenses_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (expenses.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            decimal Pprice = Convert.ToDecimal(buyTotal.Text);
            decimal expens = Convert.ToDecimal(expenses.Text);
            decimal final = Pprice + expens;
            buyTotal.Text = final.ToString();
        }
    }
```

but when i use backspace and delete number from any text box and write another number i receive wrong result , i think now it's clear i want when typing number in expenses.Text it add to buyTotal.Text and when i delete number when i typing it calculate the result

Comment: Since you are getting incorrect output, specifying *which* output is wrong, what its value is, and what the inputs where would be useful. Its going to be very difficult to answer this question as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please `KeyUp` instead of `KeyDown`, because your input value write in `textbox` after `KeyDown` event.

Please check this:

```
private void expenses_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (expenses.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        decimal Pprice = Convert.ToDecimal(buyTotal.Text);
        decimal expens = Convert.ToDecimal(expenses.Text);
        decimal final = Pprice + expens;
        buyTotal.Text = final.ToString();
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        buyTotal.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[6].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code should be enough to calculate two numbers sum :

```
private void expenses_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (expenses.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            double Pprice = Convert.ToDouble(buyTotal.Text);
            double expens = Convert.ToDouble(expenses.Text);
            double final = Pprice + expens;
            buyTotal.Text = final.ToString("0.00");
        }
        else
        {
            buyTotal.Text="0.00";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        buyTotal.Text="0.00";
    }
}
```